# Edge browser throwing: SEC7138: [CORS] The origin '' found multiple Timing-Allow-Origin response headers for cross-origin script resource at ''

Tags: cors, http-headers, microsoft-edge, response-headers

**Background:**

If you open up https://uber.com on Microsoft Edge, you will recieve:

> SEC7138: [CORS] The origin 'https://uber.com' found multiple Timing-Allow-Origin response headers for cross-origin script resource at 'some-javascript-or-svg-file'

**Question:**
What in the world does this error mean? How would one fix it?

I'm struggling to understand any of the CORS docs around `Timing-Allow-Origin`.  Luckily, the errors are seemingly innocuous.

Currently the `Timing-Allow-Origin` headers for all images and javascript files are set to `*,*`.

---

> `*` The server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to see timing resources.

---

> `<origin>` Specifies a URI that may see the timing resources. You can specify multiple origins, separated by commas.

---

Comment: I try to open the site in MS Edge but I did not got above mentioned error. If you check the documentation for the Timing-Allow-Origin than you can see that compatibility for MS Edge is still unknown. So this can be the possible reason for this error. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Timing-Allow-Origin Besides that I did not get any specific documents to solve above mentioned error.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Edge. It seems to indicate that Edge doesn’t conform to the current spec requirements that allow multiple origins in the value but instead expects there to be only one origin specified.